# What would be the radio equivalent of this ngModel text input form, using spring boot mvc and angular?

Tags: angular, radio-button, angular-ngmodel

I was taking a tutorial on making an employee CRUD model that uses spring boot and mysql server for the backend and angular for the front end. On the Create part it had this form-group (the gender part I was adding new fields).

```
    <div class="form-group">
            <label>
                Gender </label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="gender" required [(ngModel)]="employee.gender" name="gender">
        </div>
```

And that would work when submitting it (ie. creating the employee). But I can't figure out how to turn it into a radio button and submit it (it just gets stuck on the create page). This is what I tried to make when following a radio button example.

```
<div class="form-group">

            <label for [(ngModel)]="employee.gender">Gender:</label>
            <div>
                <input id="male" type="radio" value="male" name="gender" formControlName="gender">
                <label for="male">Male</label>
            </div>

            <div>
                <input id="female" type="radio" value="female" name="gender" formControlName="gender">
                <label for="female">Female</label>
            </div>
        </div>
```

My understanding could use more work, but I'm trying to learn. Any help is appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Remove ngmodel from label. Have you added gender form control to your form group?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Angular, there are [two different approaches](https://angular.io/guide/forms-overview#choosing-an-approach) when it comes to working with Forms:

- [Template-driven forms](https://angular.io/guide/forms#building-a-template-driven-form)
- [Reactive forms](https://angular.io/guide/reactive-forms#reactive-forms)

In case of Template-driven forms we make use of `ngModel` for data binding, whereas in case of Reactive forms we work with FormControls.

The 1st example shared in the question is using Template-driven approach, and the radio button equivalent code with two options to choose from, would be:

```html
<div class="form-group">
  <label>Gender:</label>
  <div>
    <input id="male" type="radio" value="male" name="gender" [(ngModel)]="employee.gender">
    <label for="male">Male</label>
  </div>

  <div>
    <input id="female" type="radio" value="female" name="gender" [(ngModel)]="employee.gender">
    <label for="female">Female</label>
  </div>
</div>
```

In case of Reactive forms approach, you can simply replace `[(ngModel)]="employee.gender"` with `formControlName="gender"` provided you have defined a FormControl named `gender` within your FormGroup.

Comment: Thank you. I will keep that in mind.

Answer (score 0):

You want to set obj `employee` prop `gender` with radio buttons.

You could group radio buttons and use `(change)` event to set the genders. I created this example a while back, it should fit your needs if you refactor this example and make `onChange(event: any)` to set the `event.value` to equal your `employee.gender`.

```html
<mat-radio-group aria-label="Select an option" (change)="onChange($event)">
  <mat-radio-button value="1">Option 1 Male</mat-radio-button>
  <mat-radio-button value="2">Option 2 Female</mat-radio-button>
  <br>
  <br>
  Selected value: {{selectedValue | json}}, send to backend sex as: {{selectedSexObj | json}}
</mat-radio-group>
```

```js
@Component({
  selector: 'radio-overview-example',
  templateUrl: 'radio-overview-example.html',
  styleUrls: ['radio-overview-example.css'],
})
export class RadioOverviewExample {
  selectedSexObj = { male: false, female: false };
  selectedValue: any;
  onChange(event: any) {
    this.selectedValue = event.value;
    if (event.value == 1) {
      this.selectedSexObj = { male: true, female: false };
    } else {
      this.selectedSexObj = { male: false, female: true };
    }
  }
}
```

Here is a working example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-qggcqg-qydurn?file=src%2Fapp%2Fradio-overview-example.ts

Comment: Yeah, I actually looked over that one before, but since I'm using the radio button with the mvc, I needed to include ngModel with it. Thanks for answering.